# Nginx reverse stream proxy for subdomains "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy to redirect tcp from subdomain.example.com to `localhost:3000` using Nginx's `ssl_preread_server_name` module.

The host `test.localhost` is defined for testing purposes in `/etc/hosts/`.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

stream {
        map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        test.localhost test;
        }

        upstream test {
                server localhost:3000;
        }

        server {
                listen 2600;
                proxy_pass $name;
                #proxy_protocol on;
                ssl_preread on;
        }
}
```

When i try the webapp directly with `curl`:

```
$ curl localhost:3000
Hello World!
```

But when i try the proxy:

```
$ curl -vvv test.localhost:2600
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:2600...
* Connected to test.localhost (127.0.0.1) port 2600 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: test.localhost:2600
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host test.localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Changing it to `proxy_pass test;` would work, but i want multiple sub domains to stream tcp to different local ports.

Answer (score 1):

The point is SSL.

May be you should try

```
curl https://test.localhost:2600
```

Comment: `$ curl https://test.localhost:2600` results in:

`curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to test.localhost:2600`

It does not work, but why would it be https?
I'm just trying to redirect tcp which can be different things, and the webapp is http.

Comment: @horkrux because the module is named 'ssl_preread_server_name'. It's used for https, not for http. If you want to redirect http, uses vhost (Server Blocks)